# How to pass array and function to Page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm getting multiple errors with `page.evaluate` and I don't understand why.

> ReferenceError: alljobs is not defined

and

> Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: multiplePositionsPerJob is not
>   defined

`alljobs` is an array I'm trying to push objects to.
`multiplePositionsPerJob` is a function that I've referenced with `require` in the file.

```
 var alljobs = [];
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll(
        "section"
      )
    ).map(job => {
      console.log(job);

      if (job.querySelector("ul li")) {
        multiplePositionsPerJob(job).forEach(position => {
          alljobs.push(position);
        });
      } 
    });
  }, alljobs);
```

Comment: you push in jobs.push(position); when you define the array variable alljobs

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. See update. @LDS

Answer (score 2):

To passing arguments like an array or functions, your code should be like this.

```
var alljobs = [];
var allFuncts = require("./functionsfile");
var multiplePositionsPerJob = allFuncts.multiplePositionsPerJob;

await page.evaluate( (alljobs, multiplePositionsPerJob) => {

    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('section') ).map(job => {
        console.log(job);

        if ( job.querySelector("ul li") ) {
            multiplePositionsPerJob(job).forEach(position => {
                alljobs.push(position);
            });
        }
    });

}, alljobs, multiplePositionsPerJob);
```

Comment: I still get the same error. multiplePositionsPerJob  is not a function. @Edi Imanto

Comment: I forgot to add allFuncts as an object not a function.